# Exporting the text in .txt format in the local drive C using Visual studio

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

Please help me. I am inputting a text in the textbox in Visual Studio but when I export it using .txt format, the notepad is unable to find in the location drive C:. Here is my code:

`My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText("C:\out.txt", "" & "Name: " + TextBox1.Text, True)`

Comment: Do you mean `"C:\out.txt"` or `"C:\\out.txt"`? Also, is the `WriteAllText` throwing an exception?

Comment: No exceptions? Are you allowed to write to the root of `C:`? @AdrianHHH VB.Net here, not C(something).

Comment: I tried changing the location into drive E: which is my flash drive and I found the created notepad there but I cannot do the same thing when it is in drive C:

Comment: Do you have any other directory in `C:`? I assume you have some. Try another. Some *place* where the current user has rights to write to. Maybe, use a `SaveFileDialog()` to pick the destination folder. Btw, the initial `"" & ` is useless; maybe you wanted to add `vbCrLf` or `Environment.Newline`. Use `&` only for string concatenation. Or use `string.Format()`. Or interpolated strings (as in `$"{vbCrLf}Name: {TextBox1.Text}"`)

Comment: I'll take note of that. Thank you!

Comment: The root of the C: drive is protected  so users cannot write to it unless the process is elevated. Why do you use C:\ ? can you create a specific folder or use Application.StartupPath?

Comment: I just created a new folder in drive C: and save my file there.

Answer (score 0):

You can tyr the code like follows.

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim result As String = TextBox1.Text.Trim()
        Dim sw As StreamWriter = File.AppendText("C:\\test.txt")
        sw.Write(result)
        sw.Flush()
        sw.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

[image]